# Visualizar textura enorme

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Saludos,

estoy trabajando en un programa desarrollado en C++, utilizando QT y GDAL. El programa ahora mismo es capaz de mostrar texturas pero si estas son más grandes que 16384x16384 pixels me aparece el siguiente error:

> GLI | GL ERROR - Function glTextureStorage2DEXT generated error GL_INVALID_VALUE

La imagen que uso como textura es un imagen en formato TIFF.

Creo que este problema se debe a que OpenGl no puede crear texturas tan grandes. El principal problema que tengo es que no puedo cambiar la resolución de la imagen ya que necesito todos los detalles de la misma, así que me gustaría si alguien sabe un método para poder tener en memoria solo el pedazo de textura que se está viendo por el visor (un QSurface de 800x800) y que a la vez pueda modificar dinamicamente dicho pedazo.

Comment: Suena a algo muy difícil de investigar. ¿Es posible que te quedes sin memoria de vídeo? Si esto sucede, comprueba si tienes el mipmapping activado y de ser así desactívalo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Metodo para usar texturas muy grandes :

Divide y venceras,
Encargate de que la textura que utilizas si mas es grande de > 8192 la cortas en 4 segmentos cuadrados y multiplos de 2.
Así sucesivamente, puedes lidiar con el tamaño que quieras.

Despues en vez de instanciar 1 objeto de dibujo, instancias 4 y los organizas de forma que queden juntos y ordenados, y asignas a cada uno una textura diferente pero que en realidad son las 4 que has generado al hacer el recorte.

Ejemplo

texturaGrande_00 -> instancia TopLeft

texturaGrande_01 -> instancia TopRight

texturaGrande_02 -> instancia BottomLeft

texturaGrande_03 -> instancia BottomRight

## Metodo para usar solo un segmento

Lo que buscas aqui es usar un area de tu imagen enorme, la estrategia a seguir es que crees un objeto tipo textura, pero leyendo solo el bound (region) que corresponda.

De tal manera teniendo una matriz ejemplo: 10x10
Queremos solo un area de 4x4, leemos los bits de la imagen gigante que cuyo (centro + la mitad de nuestro rago - lado izquierdo) sea donde empiece,
imaginando que es el centro  5 - (4/2)  = row 3 , 5 - (4/2) = col 3
empezamos a leer en 3x3 hasta 3 + bound y 3 + bound osea 7x7 y esa pequeña matriz compondra nuestra nueva imagen.

Ahora ya simplmente comandamos un swap al objeto de visualizacion que use nuestra nueva textura.

## Para editarla

Simplemente, edita la matriz pequeña a tu antojo y luego sobreescribe la region del buffer de la gigante(original) al buffer o fichero, segun necesites. El resto es repetir el proceso cada vez que desplazes la imagien.